# Descobrir ips de outros devices conectado a um android

Tags: android

O problema é mais ou menos o seguinte, as vezes preciso utilizar um aparelho com Android para gerar uma rede, mas não sei como obter os ips dos clientes conectados.

Vi alguns exemplos usando ping, em que envia ping para todos os ips disponiveis, e verifica quem respondeu, mas imagino que tenha uma forma mais eficiente de realizar isso já que quero descobrir o ip pelos aparelho que esta rotiando.